# Incrementing/decrementing ref count in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I was wondering if mongodb update can take in a condition? For eg, i am maintaining a database of IDs. If someone subscribes to this ID, i would like to increment the refcount and similarly if someone unsubscribes, want to decrement the count. However, if the count reaches zero, i want to remove this entry. Similarly, on subscribe, if the entry doesn't exist, want to add a new entry with refCount 1.

I am not sure if maintaining a list like
{'interest_list' : [{'eid': '1234', 'refCount':1}, {'eid': '4567', 'refCount':2}] is a good idea.

Appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in Mongo, however, it smell like bad practice.  Ref count is an aggregate.  Aren't you going to want to query for "all documents with zero references" rather than "all documents with no concept of reference"?

Comment: In this case, refCount is used for how often that entry being inserted in mongo.
No, my requirement is what i explained above.
Thanks

Comment: So it should start at zero or one then, not 'doesn't exist'